# Convert the iterated integral $ \int_{0}^{6}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{36-x^2}}e^{-x^2-y^2}dydx $ into polar integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, iterated-integrals

$$
\int_{0}^{6}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{36-x^2}}e^{-x^2-y^2}dydx
$$

I tried converting it into polar coordinates using the following equations

$y = \sqrt{36-x^2} \implies y^2 + x^2 = 36 \implies r = 6$

$0=6\cos\theta, 6=6\cos\theta \therefore \theta = \frac{pi}{2}, 0$

$$
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\int_{0}^{6}re^{-r^2}drd\theta \\
= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-36})d\theta \\
= \frac{\pi}{4}(e^{-36}-1)
$$

But I keep getting the answer wrong, I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The region where you are integrating can be described as:
\begin{align*}
R = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid (x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 36)\wedge(0\leq y\leq 6)\wedge(0\leq x\leq 6)\}
\end{align*}

If you make the change of variable $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$, the region $R$ can be described as
\begin{align*}
R = \{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}\times[0,2\pi) \mid (0\leq r\leq 6)\wedge(0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2)\}.
\end{align*}

Given that the correction factor in this case is given by $r$, one arrives at the desired integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{6}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{36 - x^{2}}}e^{-x^{2} - y^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{6}re^{-r^{2}}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}

From now on, I think you can handle it.

**EDIT**

Here I provide a picture of the integration region:

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. But I still don't get why I ended with my outer integral as $\frac{\pi}{2} to  0$, when I solve for $r\cos\theta$ for 0 and 6, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @currentexplanation I provided a picture of the integration region.